# What is wrong with those calculations md5 gpubruteforcing

Tags: md5

I read an article by a stackexchange founder:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

It talks about: " two ATI Radeon 7970 cards generating nearly **16000 M c/s** with MD5."

" the full range of a common US keyboard – that is, including uppercase, lowercase, numbers,     and all possible symbols:

```
all 6 character password MD5s   47 seconds

all 7 character password MD5s   1 hour, 14 minutes

all 8 character password MD5s   ~465 days
"
```

Here is the problem. Those calculations don't match:

6 characters: (95^6)/(16000*10^6)= 45.94 seconds.

7 characters: (95^7)/(16000*10^6*60*60) = 1.21 hours.

**8 characterse: (95^8)/(16000*10^6*60*60*24) = 4.79 days.**

Same for his other calculations:
"just uppercase, lowercase, and numbers" (26 lowercase, 26 uppercase, 10 numbers)

```
all 6 character password MD5s   3 seconds
all 7 character password MD5s   4 minutes
all 8 character password MD5s   4 hours
all 9 character password MD5s   10 days
all 10 character password MD5s  ~625 days
```

6 characters: (53^6)/(16000*10^6) =1.38 seconds.

7 characters: (53^7)/(16000*10^6*60)=1.22 minutes.

8 characters: (53^8)/(16000*10^6*60*60)=1.08 hours

9 characters: (53^9)/(16000*10^6*60*60*24)=2.38 days.

**10 characters: (53^10)/(16000*10^6*60*60*24)=126.51 days.**

Comment: You have dropped a zero in your calculations.  1600 should be 16000.

Answer (score 2):

95<sup>6</sup> / 16000*10<sup>6</sup> = 45.94, not 459.4. You forgot a zero: that's **16 billions** hashes per second, not **1.6 billions**. The actual figure is, as Jeff says, "nearly" 16000 millions, which means "a bit less" -- hence 47 seconds, not 46.

Add the missing zero in your computations and all the numbers will be correct.

Comment: How about the 8 characters: (95^8)/(16000*10^6*60*60*24) = 4.79 days. vs ~465 days

Comment: Well, _that_ one is off: Jeff used the figure for 9 characters instead of 8. That's a typographic error, which you could point out to him. (It doesn't change much to his point, though.)